# Delete duplicate records in MS Access that aren't exact matches

Tags: ms-access

I am working with Excel spreadsheets that I'm importing into MS Access. They include a client name, date of birth, some other personal information, and order information. The same clients often have multiple, unique orders. I am creating a table that is just unique clients (which I'll link to the order table later) and so when I import data from Excel I would like to delete duplicate client records, preserving one. I would like to match them on Name and Date of Birth. The issue I'm running into is that some client names are strings that don't match exactly.

For example:

```
Name            DOB
----            ---
DOE,JOHN        1/1/1960
DOE,JOHN L      1/1/1960
JOHNSON,PAT     12/1/1945
SMITH,BETTY     2/1/1935
```

In the above set I'd like to limit it to just three records and remove an excess John Doe record.

I basically would like to only look at the client name before the space. 
I wouldn't be opposed to losing the middle initial totally, so if there's a way to just chop it off, that'd work too. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could use something like the following, in a query, to get the name. I assume in the first 'Doe,John' there is NO space at all. MyName: IIf(InStr(1,[Name1]," ")=0,[Name1],Left([name1],InStr(1,[name1]," ")-1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your easiest option is to in fact cut off any middle initals.

You'll want to process as follows.

1. Use Select DISTINCT when all done and said.
2. If you use the InStr function [Syntax HERE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/InStr-Function-85d3392c-3b1c-4232-bb18-77cd0cb8a55b) , you can search for the space after the first name.
3. you can then choose to select only what's left of that with the Left function (left minus 1 as to not include the space). You'll come up with an error if a space isn't found, so add and iif statement to simply output just the name.
4. After reviewing the data, you'll need to remove column 1 (in the example below) as well as insert the Expr1 code directly into the iif statement, so in the end you'll only have two columns: DOB and Expr2 (or rename AS Name)

Here's an example:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Table1.Name, 
        Table1.DOB, 
        InStr(1,[Table1].[Name]," ",1) AS Expr1, 
        IIf([expr1]>0,Left([Table1].[Name],[Expr1]-1),[Table1].[Name]) AS Expr2
    FROM Table1;
```

Wayne beat me to it..

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I realized after posting that I don't want to chop off the middle initials completely (since some of them are also "Jr." or "Sr."), but I can compare the chopped off bits and DOB and it'll work great.